# implementing jquery ui dialog into .net form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I'm using an out of the box implementation of JQuery UI Dialog on a .net form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

         <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Open Me" 
             onclick="btnTest_Click" />
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>

<script>
    $("#dialog").dialog(
        { autoOpen: false });
    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
</script>  
    </form>
```

I have two questions. First, I want the content of the dialog to be dependent on some logic that happens after the button click event is processed in the codebehind. How can I do that?

Second, just testing it above in demo mode, fires the dialogue but immediately closes it. I'm assuming it has something to do with e.preventDefault(), or thats what I've read, but I'm not sure how that will factor in if I tie it to run after the postback of the form.

Comment: You are using asp:Button, so inside click function try to add return false after this line of code $("#dialog").dialog("open");   and "some logic that happens after the button click event is processed in the codebehind" mean if you want to fetch data then you can use ajax post.

Answer (score 0):

To call the server you will need to make an Ajax call to get the data you need to display:

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        width : 500,
        height : 400,
        resizable : true,
        modal : true,
        open : function()
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : //"post Url ex. Default.aspx/OpenDialog",
                data ://data to send to the server,
                dataType://the data type,
```

success : function(response)
                    {
                        $('#dialog').html(response);

```
                },
                error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert("Error: " + thrownError + "Status: " + xhr.status);
                }
            });
        },
        buttons : {
            "Close" : function()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

and in your button click you will do :

```
$("#btnTest").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in the code behind button click event. Then we can have a javascript function in the aspx page which actually has the dialog logic.

```js
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);   //in code behind file
```

```js
function myFunction(){
  // update something to dialog div
  $("#dialog").dialog(
        { autoOpen: false }
  );  
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want some value from code behind to front end?
if yes:

then at code behind :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HiddenField1.Value = " from code behind";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('Hello');", true);      
        }
```

and at aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
            font-size: 62.5%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function myFunction(a) {

            $("#dialog").text(a+$("[id$=HiddenField1]").val());
            $("#dialog").dialog();          
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">            
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it may help you.